# Connected Storage and enumerating GameSaveContainer

Tags: xbox-live

I have been looking through the Xbox Live Extensions SDK API Reference and cannot seem to find how to get an existing container by enumeration or by name. The GameSaveContainerInfo is what I can get from a CreateContainerInfoQuery, but that is informational metadata only. In order to load a game, I am assuming that I would need an existing container and query for the blobs on that one. I just cannot seem to find how to get the container.

I don't think CreateContainer is what I need because this creates a fresh one, but I could be wrong.

I am creating it under the Creators program, and checked the table which includes Title storage as well as Connected storage as available, but there is little to no information, much less for C#.

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 1):

You do need to use the GameSaveProvider.CreateContainer(string name) function to access a previously made container. Putting in the same name you used to create the container initially will allow you to pull down that same container. 
Take a look at the SaveData() and LoadData() functions in this [Xbox Live Sample code](https://github.com/Microsoft/xbox-live-samples/blob/master/Samples/ID%40XboxSDK/GameSave/Unity/Assets/GameSaveManager.cs) to get an idea of how to save and retrieve data from Connected Storage.